# Problems with Bundler when trying to upgrade rails 3.0 site from ruby 1.8.7 to 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I'm trying to upgrade all my apps from ruby 1.8.7 to 1.9.3.

Some apps are working fine. However, I have a rails 3.0.x site that keeps throwing an error about the wrong bundler version when I run it or use bundle install.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    refinerycms (~> 0.9.8.5) ruby depends on
      bundler (~> 1.0.0) ruby

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.2.3)

This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?
```

I have both bundler 1.2.3 installed (required for passenger) and bundler 1.0.22.  However, it wont let me run `bundle install`, and running the site also throws an error that rails 3.0 requires the older version of bundler.

UPDATE:
I got my gems installed using the older version of bundler:

```
bundle _1.0.3_ install
```

This worked fine as far as installing gems, however when i run the site, Passenger still complains that i'm using bundler 1.2.3 and it needs (~>1.0.0).  Doesn't ~> mean "greater than 1.0" ?  I don't have any of these problems under Ruby 1.8.7.

Here is my Gemfile.  As you can see, I have tried including the older version of bundler in my gemfile and excluding. Neither way works. :(

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'


#gem 'bundler', '1.0.3'
gem 'rails', '3.0.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2', '0.2.6'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug'

# Bundle the extra gems:
# gem 'bj'
# gem 'nokogiri'
# gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
# gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'

# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
# group :development, :test do
#   gem 'webrat'
# end

# REFINERY CMS ================================================================

# Specify the Refinery CMS core:
gem 'refinerycms',              '~> 0.9.8.5'

# Specify additional Refinery CMS Engines here (all optional):
gem 'refinerycms-inquiries',    '~> 0.9.8.10'
gem 'refinerycms-search',       '~> 0.9.8'
gem "refinerycms-news",         '~> 0.9.9'

# Add i18n support (optional, you can remove this if you really want to).
gem 'refinerycms-i18n',         '~> 0.9.8.7'

# Figure out how to get RMagick:
rmagick_options = {:require => false}
rmagick_options.update({
  :git => 'git://github.com/refinerycms/rmagick.git',
  :branch => 'windows'
}) if Bundler::WINDOWS

# Specify a version of RMagick that works in your environment:
gem 'rmagick',                  '~> 2.12.2', rmagick_options

# END REFINERY CMS ============================================================

# USER DEFINED


# END USER DEFINED
gem 'validates_timeliness', '~> 3.0.0'

engine_path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'vendor/engines')

#puts engine_path

gem 'refinerycms-venues', '1.0', :path => "./vendor/engines", :require => 'venues'
gem 'refinerycms-events', '1.0', :path => './vendor/engines', :require => 'events'
gem 'refinerycms-available_spaces', '1.0', :path => './vendor/engines', :require => 'available_spaces'
gem 'refinerycms-contents', '1.0', :path => 'vendor/engines', :require => 'contents'
gem 'refinerycms-news_alerts', '1.0', :path => 'vendor/engines', :require => 'news_alerts'
```

Its like Rails 3.0 will NOT allow me to run the site if i have a newer version of bundler installed, but that seems insane.  Would having a newer version of bundler break older sites?

Comment: Would you mind post your Gemfile here or some pastebin?

Comment: You can post your own answer to your question and accept it. That's recommended practice here. :)

Comment: i didn't come up with an answer.  I just was stating that i added the gemfile.  I still can't run a rails 3.0 site with a newer bundler installed.  :(

Comment: Try to uninstall all versions of Bundler on your machine and then install the 1.0.x version only

Comment: that works but its unacceptable in a QA or production environment where gems may be shared.  its even inconvenient in development.

Comment: I would recommend you upgrade to latest RefineryCMS thus will depends on more current Rails/Bundler so you don't have this problem at all

Comment: why do you need to install both bundler 1.2.3 and bundler 1.0.3 in same QA/production environment?

Comment: because i have some sites running later versions of rails and some using older ones.  Unfortunately, i do not yet have RVM setup for these sites on this prod server.